# OAuth 2 - What is the difference between 'Username and Password Flow' vs 'Client Credential Flow'

Tags: oauth-2.0

In both cases the users credentials are being exchanged for an access token.  Can someone explain the difference?

Here is a description of the flows from http://hueniverse.com

```
• User-Agent Flow – for clients running inside a user-agent (typically a web browser).
• Web Server Flow – for clients that are part of a web server application, accessible via HTTP requests. This is a simpler version of the flow provided by OAuth 1.0.
• Device Flow – suitable for clients executing on limited devices, but where the end-user has separate access to a browser on another computer or device.
• Username and Password Flow – used in cases where the user trusts the client to handle its credentials but it is still undesirable for the client to store the user’s username and password.  This flow is only suitable when there is a high degree of trust between the user and the client.
• Client Credentials Flow – the client uses its credentials to obtain an access token. This flow supports what is known as the 2-legged scenario.
• Assertion Flow – the client presents an assertion such as a SAML assertion to the authorization server in exchange for an access token.
```

Answer (score 9):

You're mixing up *client* and *user* credentials here.

*Client* in the context of OAuth always refers to the application that gets authorized. Thus in the *Client Credentials Flow* an application directly authorizes itself with the provider without any input from a user (also called [*2-legged flow*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6949008/1467115) as only two parties are involved).

The *Username and Password Flow* is a *3-legged-flow*. A user provides his username and password to an application, the application then requests data from the provider using these credentials.

Comment: Ah thank you - that makes more sense than whats provided in the spec - I think the terminology the picked is confusing since the definition changes with context